# Maven Reference Pom in Child Module By Name

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

We are using a parent pom that has a child module where we have 2 pom files - the one named `pom.xml` and other being `images-pom.xml`.
This is the situation because we are doing some naming changes and for the time being we want to have them both.
In our parent pom we have the following code

```
<modules>
   <module>child</module>
</modules>

<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

By default it seems that this is looking and trying to build the `pom.xml` - but in reality we want to use the `images-pom.xml` Is there any way to achieve this without creating a new module and using profiles?

Comment: Can you please describe more in detail why you need two different pom files (images-pom.xml) and which kind of naming changes because it's unclear what you like to achieve?

Comment: We are renaming our microservice - we want to rename jars, etc, but we want to have both of the jar names at the same time.

Comment: If you like to have a different name use the appropriate artifactId ... Please make an example to show how that looks like...